# how to use code to adjust the arrange order in zencart?

Tags: php, zen-cart

i want to change the default arrange order of the product's output on the home page of my site. how to change it? thank you. the default order is `Featured Products`  `New Products For October`  `Monthly Specials For October`.

now i want  the order is `New Products For October`  `Monthly Specials For October` `Featured Products`. how should i do? thank you.

Answer (score 2):

you can find file named "tpl_index_default.php" under /includes/templates\template_default_ORyour_template\templates

all modules included here. you can adjust the arrange order here.